# make the textbox readonly but still send the data into the server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I want to make textbox in asp.net c# readonly which means not giving the user the ability to write but I attached a datepicker for it once it is focused on. When I choose from the datepicker the date is printed on the textbox which is perfect but it doesnt send the date to the server. Any suggestion how to resolve this issue?

Comment: web form or mvc ? why you do not use from script in your page for set read only and date picker  on that ?

Comment: `doesnt send the date to the server.` what does that mean? Can you share the code which is trying to access the date from textBox? What value you are getting when try access the text from the textbox?

Comment: exactly @ChetanRanpariya says right, cuz why you want make a read only text box but set the date picker on it and finally you do not want send to server ?!!